# How to capture errors from a library function that throws no exceptions (`ars`)?

Tags: r, rpy2

I'm using the `ars` (Adaptive Rejection Sampling) library to sample a given variable from a concave density distribution.

The thing is that the `ars` function prints "*ifault codes*" when something is wrong, but apparently it does not throw any exception.

```
library(ars)

f<-function(x,mu=0,sigma=1){-1/(2*sigma^2)*(x-mu)^2}
fprima<-function(x,mu=0,sigma=1){-1/sigma^2*(x-mu)}
# mysample<-ars(1,f,fprima,mu=2,sigma=3) # it gives no errors
mysample<-ars(1,f,fprima,mu=2,sigma=3, x=c(2,4)) # bad choice of x
hist(mysample)
```

The problem is that I call the `ars` function from python using `rpy2` and I need my program to know whether the `ars` has been able to generate the sample. That is, I would like `ars` to throw a real exception or return some special value.

How can I catch the error?

Comment: `if( grepl( '<text of ifault code here>', <variable containing response>) ) stop('<your own error message here>')`

Comment: The value of the variable `mysample` is not the ifault code :(

Comment: Why not rewrite the code of `ars` so that it behaves in the nmanner you expect? The comment from  `doicomehereoften` is unlikely to be helpful since the code shows that the messages are constructed with `cat` which is only a side-effect.

Comment: Because (I thought) it was not trivial since the code uses external c libraries. But I'm realizing now that it's straightforward...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rewrite the code so that the conclusion portions do what you desire. This might be one possible variation of the last portions of the function:

```
ars2 <- function (n = 1, f, fprima, x = c(-4, 1, 4), ns = 100, m = 3, 
    emax = 64, lb = FALSE, ub = FALSE, xlb = 0, xub = 0, ...) 
{
# leave top portion the same
#......
            else {
                return( list(msg= "Error in sobroutine sample_...", ifault= sample$ifault))
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        return( list(msg="\nError in sobroutine initial_...", ifault= initial$ifault))
    }
    return(mysample)
}
# Then finish up by setting the environment for ars2
environment(ars2) <- environment(ars)
```

Comment: And then you call the new function it by `ars` or `ars2`?

Comment: I'm not sure how this is set up, i.e. I don't know if you can do this from an R-console and expect python to connect or alternatively you would need to send all this from a python-delivered script. (And the second option could be done only once at the beginning of a session.) A third (or is that really only the second?) option would be to rewrite the R-package before loading.  But I'm sure you would call `ars2` from python once the set up was done.

Comment: From `R` would be enough. It is weird, I think I got to get a `mysample` list with the ifault code and so but I can't reproduce it anymore. I pasted my current code.

Comment: I see an extraneous comma in my return list  which I am correcting. (You faithfully copied my suggestion which I admit was untested, but it now returns the two item error list)

Comment: True! Got it! Thanks! :)